# Typless Entity Patch operation in ODATA v4

Tags: dynamic, entity, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm workng on supporting the patch operation for a typeless entity in odata v4 with webapi.

So far the only thing that I was able to make work was the Put operation, but it requires the whole object to be present.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(IEdmEntityObject entity)
{
     return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Whenever I change the Put verb to be a Patch, the `entity` object is null.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Patch(IEdmEntityObject entity)
{
     return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I also tried replaceing the `IEdmEntityObject` with the types - `Delta`, `Delta<IEdmEntityObject>` and `dynamic` but i get the following exception

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Object' from content with media type 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gebov

Update, for example PATCH/PUT is for a single entity. So, your action should have a key to identify which entity should to be updated.

Therefore, modify your action as:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Patch(int key, IEdmEntityObject entity)
{
   ...
}
```

It should work. See my [test project](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/commit/b95d0ca43c9b89e3763ba016253431770147e937). Thanks.

Comment: That gets an entry point into the Patch method, but your code example doesn't follow the PATCH paradigm, If I don't pass through the Name property, the code still evaluates a value of null for Name, but this is incorrect, we need to know how to check if Name was provided by the request data at all, not just check for nullability. I'll write up a question specific to this but just want to catch the eye of anyone else who might have a solution to this.

Comment: Turns out, cast entity to Delta, then we can access GetChangedProeprtyNames(), I'm going to be a little be presumptuous and edit your answer with this to make it a more complete example of Patch logic.